# How can I assign a function to a variable without executing it?

Tags: go

When I try to assign a map key to a function it executes the function. How can I do this without executing the function?

```
var myslice []int
myslice = append(myslice, 1)

func RemoveIndex(s []string, index int) []string {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}

a["removeIndex"] = removeIndex(myslice, 0)
```

Comment: `a["removeIndex"] = removeIndex`. If you add parantheses to the end, the function will be invoked, without the parentheses it will not.

Comment: You seem to have found the answer you want, but the question isn't clear to me at all. I assume the code fragments are snippets from a larger example, but as it stands, the code won't compile or run. The type of `a` for example is important, and what behavior you want is unclear. For a good stack overflow question, it's better to include a minimal but complete example, and a clear statement of what you're trying to achieve (other than "not executing a function" which is quite easy to not do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign the function to the `map[string]func([]string,int)[]string`'s key

```
func RemoveIndex(s []string, index int) []string {
    return append(s[:index], s[index+1:]...)
}

a["removeIndex"] = RemoveIndex

rifn := a["removeIndex"]

rifn(myslice, 0)
```